# c# - find the right element in a list

Tags: c#, list, find

I need to get the first not null occurrence in a list, this is the code but there are few cases I need to handle:

```
string field = new List<string>() {field1, field2, field3, field4,}.Find(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) );
```

this works, but this is the case I need to handle: if field1='abc' and field 2='def' I need to take the field 2, so if field1='abc' I need to take the first field !='abc' and not null, if the other fields are null I need to take field1, how I can do this in the find?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the second non-null element, and if there's no such element the first one?

Comment: ^ Or the first non-null element that is not "abc". Otherwise, the first element that is "abc"?

Comment: @devNull yeah, that's what I meant

Comment: My question was more about this: is `"abc"` *the first non-null element* or is it a **constant**? Those are two quite different approaches

Comment: @Rafalon it's a constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should answer your question with a simple `for` loop and some `if`s:

```
// First non-null different from 'abc' unless there's none
// then first non-null
static string SecondOrFirstNonNull(List<string> list)
{
    string s = null;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        // We found a non-null element..
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[i]))
        {
            s = list[i];
            
            // .. and it's different from 'abc' !
            if(list[i] != "abc")
            {
                // so we can stop iterating through the list
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Approach with `Skip()`

```
string field1 = null, field2 = "abc", field3 = "def", field4 = null;
string[] input = { field1, field2, field3, field4};
string result = input.SkipWhile(x => x != "abc").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DmGQi0

Comment: "if the other fields are null I need to take field1" - I assume OP means that, in this case, if `field3` is also null then the result should be "abc". Which this currently doesn't do. But I could be misunderstanding the question